# XCode 4.5 iOS6 failure to instantiate view controller

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, ios6, xcode4.5

I upgraded my device to iOS 6, & so I had to upgrade XCode from 4.3.3 to 4.5.2, and now my App won't work, whereas it was working very fine earlier (i.e. before the upgrade). The issue is that a view isn't getting instantiated. This line is not getting executed:

```
in Home.h
#import "ViewController_Album.h"
...
@class ViewController_Album;
...
@interface Home
...
@property (nonatomic, retain) ViewController_Album *viewAlbum;
...



in Home.m

@synthesize viewAlbum;
...
...
    - (void)viewDidLoad {
        self.viewAlbum = (ViewController_Album *) [((com_AppDelegate *) [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate]).storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"ViewController_Album"];
        NSLog(@"call album.initview");
        [self.viewAlbum initializeView];

    }
```

And in Storyboard

[image]
[image]

I have set both the 'Storyboard ID' (which is new) & also 'Title' to ViewController_Album. So it should work! However, I see that  [self.viewAlbum initializeView] is not getting called (as I tried with print statements within this method & none of them are getting printed). So it should be because viewAlbum is not getting instantiated! Why is it? This however works for few other pages in the App (am using the same code to instantiate them & they are working fine even post-upgrade!)

Please help.

Comment: Check if [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate]).storyboard is not nil.

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue ; looks like viewDidLoad of the home page was getting called even before 'didfinishLaunchingWithOptions' of AppDelegate was completed! So, I was having the storyboard initialization in didfinishLaunchingWithOptions,  & so it didn't work ! Now, I moved my code to viewWillAppear() instead. Now, it works fine!